# fgetcsv array print failing

Tags: php, fgetcsv

!! Revised !! 
For some reason it's only printing one line of the csv, and double printing the country?
[image: csv preview]
[image: output]

```
<?php
$file = fopen('storelistdata.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
list($country[], $state[], $city[], $loc[]) = $line;
$arrayLength = count($line);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $arrayLength) {
echo "<a class=\"item\">" . $loc[$i] .",". $city[$i] .",". $state[$i] .",".$country[$i] . "<a/></br>";
$i++;
}
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

CSV file

```
United States,Alabama,Alburn,Earth Fare
United States,Alabama,Huntsville,Earth Fare
United States,Alabama,Montgomery,Earth Fare
United States,Alabama,Hoover,Earth Fare
United States,Alabama,Fairhope,Fairhope Health Foods
```

Code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('storelistdata.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
 // Extract line array into these variables
 list($country, $state, $city, $loc) = $line;
 echo "<a class=\"item\">$loc, $city, $state, $country</a>\n";
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Result:

```
<a class="item">Earth Fare, Alburn, Alabama, United States</a>
<a class="item">Earth Fare, Huntsville, Alabama, United States</a>
<a class="item">Earth Fare, Montgomery, Alabama, United States</a>
<a class="item">Earth Fare, Hoover, Alabama, United States</a>
<a class="item">Fairhope Health Foods, Fairhope, Alabama, United States</a>
```

Comment: Not sure why it won't print multiple lines? updated my post above to include screenshots of the csv

Comment: is the list function only putting the first line into those variables?

Comment: Thanks Chris, for some reason it's still not printing correctly - If this prints for you, I'm going to try it on a different server, i think somethings iffy with my php system.

Comment: Best part of this is I found out shopify doesn't support PHP. Converting this to javascript as we speak :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error on this line:

```php
  echo "<a class="item">" . $loc[$i] .",". $state[i] .",". $country[i] . "<a/>";
```

For `$state[i]` and `$country[i]`, they should be `$state[$i]` and `$country[$i]` respectively.

Comment: Yup, part of it for sure! Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my syntax and still getting a weird print now :/

Comment: Look at Chris White's response. His is cleaner. There's no reason you need nested while loops.